# What does the numbers at the console mean?

Tags: javascript

What do these numbers on the left mean? I was using regex and used conditionals to verify them but it seems that it triggers both of them

[image]

Comment: That exact line has been logged that number of times. There is a setting for this in the console - it's something like "group logs".

Comment: Is it important?

Comment: Umm about as important as the line being logged, I guess? If you don't care about the logged line, then - no, it's not important. If you do care that the line is called, you'd want to know if it's logged more than once.

Comment: So if I have a file with 8 lines it means that it veryfied those 8 lines and showed the condition result?

Comment: It means the line "Valid File" has been logged 8 times one after another with no other logs between them. That's about what it means, unless you have knowledge of why that log is showing up. It might be once per file, it might be once per line in a file, or something else entirely.

Comment: Is there any explanation for why is the second conditional is being shown?

Comment: Again, it depends on what that log means. The *only* thing I can say is that it's logged twice. I am not familiar with that library nor what it does, so I'm not sure why you're asking me.

Comment: Well.....cuz you answered me

Comment: About what the number means. In the console it means the line has been logged that amount of times. This is general console behaviour, not something I need to understand a library for.

Comment: Bruh I understand it now

Comment: Firefox does the same thing, except it's over on the right side of the line instead of the left.  Hovering my mouse over it tells me "7 repeats".  It might do that in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number next to the log shows you how many consecutive times that particular message got logged.

So in your case, you received a log / console log stating "Valid File" 8 times in a row, before receiving a log / console .log stating "Invaild File"

Answer (score 2):

That number reflects how many times that log has been triggered consecutively. It groups it so it doesn't flood the console with several redundant lines.